# EXTEND method in collections plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

This is the program

```
DECLARE
     TYPE t1 IS
          TABLE OF NUMBER(10);
     v_t   t1 := t1(10,20,30,40);
BEGIN
     dbms_output.put_line(v_t.first);
     dbms_output.put_line(v_t.last);
     dbms_output.put_line(v_t.PRIOR(2) );
     dbms_output.put_line(v_t.next(2) );
     v_t.extend;
     v_t.extend(2);
     v_t.extend(3,2);
     v_t(5) := 50;
     v_t(6) := 60;
     v_t(7) := 70;
     v_t.trim;
     dbms_output.put_line(v_t.count);
     FOR i IN v_t.first..v_t.last LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(v_t(i) );
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*output:*

```
1
4
1
3
9
10
20
30
40
50
60
70
20
20
```

Here I can't understand the output of this program please anyone explain about this output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part did you not understand specifically?  Please go through the documentation to understand the collection methods: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS99967

Answer (score 1):

```
1 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t.first) - returns the first subscript/index value of 
    t1(10,20,30,40) which is 1
4 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t.last) - returns the last subscript/index value of 
    t1(10,20,30,40) which is 4
1 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t.PRIOR(2)) - returns the subscript that precedes index n in a 
    collection which is 1. 
3 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t.next(2)) - returns the subscript that succeeds index n in a 
    collection which is 3.
9 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t.count) - v_t.EXTEND appends one null element to the collection, v_t.EXTEND appends 2 null elements to the collection and v_t.EXTEND(3,2) appends 3 copies of the 2nd element to the collection
10 = dbms_output.put_line(v_t(i) - Prints all the elements.
20
30
40
50
60
70
20 = v_t.extend(3,2) - Added 3 copies of 2nd element which is 20
20 = v_t.extend(3,2) -                   ""
```

Third copy(20) is excluded because v_t.trim removes one element from the end of the collection

Comment: Thanks for your valuable explanation